# row with radiobutton in ListView with arrayadapter

Tags: android-listview

I come among you with the following problem, I try to create a frame from which you can add to a button containing new views radiogroup composed of several radiobuttons ..
The trouble is with my code, I find unwanted behavior, for example:
When I add more row, if the first one I check rabiobuttons, I scroll down and then I scroll up my screen to go see my first row ... My radionbutton is unchecked (so recycling problem of view, while I forced the backup data in my code)
And when I check a radiobutton and I add new rows via the button which I mentioned earlier, at that time some radiobutton is checked off or on automatically.

Here is my code, could you tell me where is my mistake?

A piece of my frame:

```
    final ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.slide_cavite, null);
    listview_cavite = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.listview_cavite);
    // Arbre.table_cavite.open();

    adaptor = new Adaptor_cavite_item(root.getContext(),
            R.layout.slide_item_cavite, Arbre.liste_cavite);
    listview_cavite.setAdapter(adaptor);
    ajouter_cavite = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.ajouter_cavite);
    ajouter_cavite.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Arbre.liste_cavite.add(new Donnees_cavite());
            adaptor.add(new Donnees_cavite(root.getContext()));
            adaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

The data object represented in a row :

```
    public class Donnees_cavite {


        int rb_excrement_checked;

        public int get_rb_excrement_checked() {
        return rb_excrement_checked;
        }

        public void setFirstChecked(int firstChecked) {
        this.rb_excrement_checked = firstChecked;
        }


        public Donnees_cavite(Context context){
            this.rb_excrement_checked = -1;
        }

    }
```

And my custom arrayadapter :

```
    public class Adaptor_cavite_item extends ArrayAdapter<Donnees_cavite> {

        int layoutResourceId;
        Holder holder;
        ArrayList<Donnees_cavite> liste;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        ...

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = convertView;


            if (row == null) {

                row = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_item_cavite, null);

                holder = new Holder();

                holder.excrement = (RadioGroup) row.findViewById(R.id.slide_cavite_excrement);
                holder.excrement_1 = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.slide_cavite_excrement_rb1);
                holder.excrement_2 = (RadioButton) row.findViewById(R.id.slide_cavite_excrement_rb2);

                row.setTag(this.holder);

            }else{
                this.holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
            }


            holder.excrement.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (arg1) {
                    case R.id.slide_cavite_excrement_rb1:
                        liste.get(position).setFirstChecked(1);
                        break;

                    case R.id.slide_cavite_excrement_rb2:
                        liste.get(position).setFirstChecked(2);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            });


            if (liste.get(position).get_rb_excrement_checked() == 1){
                holder.excrement_1.setChecked(true);
                holder.excrement_2.setChecked(false);
            }else{
                holder.excrement_1.setChecked(false);
                holder.excrement_2.setChecked(true);
            }

            return row;

        }

        static class Holder {
            RadioGroup excrement;
            RadioButton excrement_1,excrement_2; 

            }
        }

    }

            if (liste.get(position).get_rb_excrement_checked() == 1){
                holder.excrement_1.setChecked(true);
                holder.excrement_2.setChecked(false);
            }else if (liste.get(position).get_rb_excrement_checked() == 2){
                holder.excrement_1.setChecked(false);
                holder.excrement_2.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                holder.excrement_1.setChecked(false);
                holder.excrement_2.setChecked(false);
            }
```

Thank you for your help!

edit : The worst thing is that if I replace this piece of code at the end of my arrayadapter:

```
if (liste.get(position).get_rb_excrement_checked() == 1){
                holder.excrement_1.setChecked(true);
                holder.excrement_2.setChecked(false);
            }else if (liste.get(position).get_rb_excrement_checked() == 2){
                holder.excrement_1.setChecked(false);
                holder.excrement_2.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                holder.excrement_1.setChecked(false);
                holder.excrement_2.setChecked(false);
}
```

by

```
if (liste.get(position).get_rb_excrement_checked() == 1){
                holder.excrement_1.setChecked(true);
                holder.excrement_2.setChecked(false);
            }else{
                holder.excrement_1.setChecked(false);
                holder.excrement_2.setChecked(true);
}
```

No more unwanted behavior! everything works .. Already, I can not understand why the original code causes my "bugs" ^ ^ and then, well, this code works .. but it does not suit me as I must use radiogroup with 3,4 ... radiobutton ^^